# Automatic placing of one png image into anther one

Tags: python, perl, automation, png

I would like to know whether it is possible to carry out such an operation, that one picture is placed into another one at exact coordinates, automatedly.

I have a set consisting of 20 pairs of images of fixed size. I need to merge the pairs by placing first image of a pair to a fixed position on the second image.

I might need to do this mergers several times in future, so I am interested if there is a chance to write a scrypt in Python/Perl or any other simple language to handle this task. I am now using GIMP scripts, but most of the work still needs to be carried out manually...

Anyway, if this is not an option, I am asking someone to be so kind and briefly explain why is it so.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I will post more in case I encounter troubles, in any other case this thread may well be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a lot of recepies [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Compositing Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/). And you need [perl-magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php).